# using WPF Caliburn, How do I change datagrid binding based on the combobox selection?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, caliburn

about to add the following features

[image]

If select this combobox, I want to change the itemssource of the datagrid.

Are there any examples related to this?

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

1. Create a WPF project.
2. Create a view (xaml) with the combobox and datagrid inside it.
3. Create a view model for this newly created view and declare public properties (collection/list) for the ItemsSource of the combobox and the grid. Also have a property for the selected item of the combobox.
4. Set this view model as the data context of your view.
5. In the setter of the combobox's selected item - change the property which is bound to the datagrid's ItemsSource to the collection that you by calling a method or however you wish.

Answer (score 0):

I did this:

Add the namespace for caliburn in xaml

```
xmlns:cal="http://www.caliburnproject.org"
```

Here is the combobox:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding ComboBoxItemSource}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}" cal:Message.Attach="[Event SelectionChanged] = [ComboBoxSelectionChanged()]" />
```

and the viewmodel should be having this method:

```
public void ComboBoxSelectionChanged()
    {
        // here based on the SelectedItem you can change the ItemSource for the dataGrid.
    }
```

Whenever you are changing the selectedItem of Combobox the method will get hit and based on the logic that you need you can assign the ItemSource for the dataGrid.

Hope this helps :)